# Open clicked image from array in modal

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm working on a picture gallery for a project and tried to do something more complex(for me) for learning purposes.

I'm using an bootstrap accordion where I import every image from a folder (src/images/portofolio) in 2 arrays. Some are in the open accordion, some in the collapsible. So good so far, but I also want that when an image is clicked it pops up bigger in a bootstrap modal.

Here is a fiddle with the index.js file including the accordion

https://jsfiddle.net/mwe324ut/

In portofolioData.js I imported every image in each's coresponding array

`export const hiddenImages = [{image: img14}, {image: img15}]`

As it is now, every image that I want is displayed and when I click on a image the modal shows up, but the problem is that it displays only one certain image.

Answer (score 0):

When iterating through the images in the render function, set an `onClick` event to every image where you set a state variable of the chosen image (the index of the image for example) and then when the modal shows up, render the image that matches the index of the chosen image in state. Something like this:

```
{images.map((image, index) =>
    <img src={image} onClick={() => this.setState({ chosenImage: index })} />
)}
```

and then get the chosen image in the modal by calling:

```
hiddenImages[this.state.chosenImage]
```